# body{ height: 1000px; } in css file doesn't work but works inline

Tags: html, css

Both files are in folder atom. html is in atom/. css is in atom/css/.
Why doesn't "body{ height: 1000px;}" change body height, but inline css in  does?
I learned this after trying unsuccessfully to get body to contain all divs.
Using atom editor and using firefox and chrome to view the page with dev tools.
Any help would be greatful. Sorry if all of the code is an eyesore I am just learning html by myself and finding quite a few pitfalls.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1">
  <title>
    Secular Humanists of Rochester
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bodyfixed.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

```
Cache-Control: max-age=8640;
body{
  height: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly. Remove that 'cache control' line from top of CSS.

Although even when you put it, I can see the height is about 1000px.

```css
body{
  height: 1000px;
}
#navi{
  /*background-color: #bf0000;*/
  display: inline;
  /*top| left| bottom| right*/
}
#navbar{
  /*margin:auto;*/
  display: inline;
  width: 52%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  margin-left: 1em;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0.8em 0em 1.2em 0em;
}
#rectanglelink{
  background-color: #bf0000;
  /*border:1px #ccc solid;*/
}
.listsw{
  text-decoration: none;
  /*background-color: white;*/
  border:1px black solid;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 0.75em 1em 0.5em 1em;
}
.listsb{
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: black;
  border:1px black solid;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.75em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.learnmore{
  text-decoration: none;
  /*background-color: white;*/
  border:1px black solid;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 1em 1em 0.75em 1em;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.headlink{
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
  /*border:1px white solid;*/
  color: black;
  font-family: verdana,courier,arial;
  padding: 0em 0.5em;
  word-spacing: 0em;
  font-family: helvetica,courier,arial;
}.headlinkf{
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
  /*border:1px white solid;*/
  color: #4267B2;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: verdana,courier,arial;
  padding: 0em 0.5em;
  word-spacing: 0em;
  font-family: helvetica,courier,arial;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}
#shorhead{
  display: inline;
  /*text-decoration: bold;*/
}
#linky{
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: center;
  margin-top: 1.2em;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39%;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
#opacity{
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}
.container{
  position: relative;
  /*top: center;*/
  /*color: black;*/
  /*
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  */
}
.centered{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 5%;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  width: 45%;
  height: 80%;

}
#gardens{
  z-index: 0;
  width: 99.95%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  /*display: inline;*/
}
#textimage{
  z-index: 4;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 29%;
  left: 15%;
  width: 100%;
}
#textimage2{
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 5;
  font-size: 4vw;
  width: 68%;
  padding: 1%;
  font-family: helvetica,courier,arial;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#linky2{
  position: absolute;
  left: 7.5%;
  font-family: helvetica,courier,arial;
}
#aboutus{
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 12.7%;
  top: 5.4em; <!-- or 5.4em or 13.5em-->
  bottom: 5.4em;
  /*background-color: blue;*/
  text-align: center;
}
#abouttext{
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 0.8%;
  font-family: verdana,helvetica,courier,arial;
  line-height: 200%;
}
#hands{
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
}
#aboutustitle{
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: helvetica,courier,arial;
  padding-top: 3.5%;
}
#gardens{
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#hand{
  width: 100%;
}
#onehundredpx{
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  float: left;
}
#whatishumanism1{
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 12.7%;
  margin-top: 25.4em; <!-- or 5.4em or 13.5em-->
  bottom: 5.4em;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  /*z-index: 100;*/
}
#colorpeople{
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
}
#world{
  width: 90%;
}
#humanismtext{
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 0.8%;
  font-family: verdana,helvetica,courier,arial;
  line-height: 200%;
  font-weight: bold;
  /*background-color: blue;*/
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1">
  <title>
    Secular Humanists of Rochester
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bodyfixed.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="navi">
      <div id="navbar">
        <h1 id="shorhead">Secular Humanists of Rochester</h1>
      </div>

      <div id="linky">
        <a class="headlink" href="http://secularhumanistsofrochester.org">Home</a>
        <a class="headlink" href="#about">About</a>
        <a class="headlink" href="#what">What We Do</a>
        <a class="headlink" href="#Contact">Contact Us</a>
        <a class="headlink" target="_blank" href="https://www.meetup.com/Rochester-Secular-Humanism-Meetup/">Join</a>
        <a class="headlinkf" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/Rochester.Humanists">f</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
    <!--<a id="rectanglelink" href="meetup.com">Meetup</a>-->
  <div class="container">
    <img id="gardens" src="images/gardens-of-ireland.jpg">

    <div class="centered">
      <div id="opacity"></div>
      <div id="textimage">
        <div id="textimage2">
          Secular Humanists of<br> Rochester
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="linky2">

          <a class="listsw" target="_blank"  href="https://www.meetup.com/Rochester-Secular-Humanism-Meetup/">Meetup</a>
          <a class="listsb" target="_blank"  href="https://www.facebook.com/Rochester.Humanists">Facebook</a>
          <a class="listsw" href="forum">Forum</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container"><div id="about"></div>
    <div id="aboutus">
      <div id="hands"><img id="hand" src="images/colorful-silhouette-hands-background-design-1589987555Wea.jpg"></div>
      <div id="abouttext">
        <div id="aboutustitle">About Us</div>
        <br><br>
        The Secular Humanists of Rochester is an affiliate of the American Humanist Association, a 75-year-old organization that has proudly served as the leading voice in America on behalf of humanists, atheists, agnostics, and freethinkers.
        <br><br><br>
        <a class="learnmore">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="container"><div id="whatishumanism"></div>
    <div id="whatishumanism1">
      <div id="colorpeople"><img id="world" src="images/globe-304586_edited_edited.png"></div>
      <div id="humanismtext">
        <!--<div id="aboutustitle">About Us</div>-->
        <br><br>
        So what is humanism anyway? It is a nontheistic worldview with ethical values informed by scientific knowledge and driven by a desire to meet the needs of people in the here and now. At the foundation of those values is affirmation of the dignity of every human being.
        <br><br><br>
        <a class="learnmore">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
<!--
<div class="container">
  <div id="onehundredpx"></div><div>hi</div>
</div>
-->
```

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed it! Eventually I will need to know how to get cache control working some how.